# Question on Finding the Correct Emission Tax $t$

Tags: microeconomics, profit-maximization, social-choice, externalities

Let there be two companies $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ where, initially $U_{1}$ produces and sells $x$ units at $p=18$. Production costs are $C_{U_{1}}(x)=\frac{1}{6}x^3$ and in the process $a$ units of greenhouse gas is emitted, where $x=20a$.

> I then calculated the profit-maximizing output $x^{*}=6$, while the
>   units of GHG emitted is $a^{*}=0,3$ and the profit is
>   $G_{U_{1}}(x^{*})=72$.

Next assume that the second company $U_{2}$ starts producing. It produces $y$ units of a different good, so that $U_{1}$ profits from it. Namely $G_{1}(x)=18x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+4y$, while $U_{1}$'s production has a negative effect on the profit of $U_{2}$, namely $G_{U_{2}}(y)=24y-y^2-200a$

> I then determined the profit-maximizing output of $U_{2}$ which is
>   $y^{*}_{U_{2}}=12$ as well as the profit
>   $G_{2}(y^{*})=144-200\frac{6}{20}=84$

**Now my problem:**
How high would an emission tax $t$ have to be, so that $U_{1}$ selects the most efficient number of units to produce, meaning that the effects on $U_{2}$ are completely internalized.

Normally, if $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ were producing the same goods I would simply look at maximizing $G_{1}+G_{2}$, however, $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ are producing different goods. Surely, in order for $U_{1}$ to internalize the negative effects it has on $U_{2}$, it needs to completely halt its production.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You have indicated that the emissions from $U_1$'s production affect $U_2$'s profit.  But what is the process or mechanism by which $U_2$'s production or output affects $U_1$'s profit?  In other words, what lies beyond the formula $G_{1}(x)=18x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+4y$?

Comment: @AdamBailey I was only given the formula and it said the $U_{1}$ profits from the $U_{2}$'s production of $y$ units.